# how to upload files on a windows sharing network using python

Tags: python, samba

I am using a mac machine. I have access to a windows share network. I am able to connect to it from my mac using 'smb://location'.

Using python, I want to be able to download/upload files on the windows share network using my access credentials. How can I do it.

The shared location looks like `smb://v1/abc`. I am able to connect to this. Now I want to create a file in a folder within this connection.

I want to create a file inside the folder `d2`. I tried using [`pysmb`](http://pythonhosted.org/pysmb/api/smb_SMBConnection.html) module. I tried the following:

```
>>> fp = open('local_file.txt', 'w')
>>> conn = SMBConnection('user', 'password', 'test_v1','v1', use_ntlm_v2 = True)
>>> conn.retrieveFile('share', 'abc/d2/check.csv', fp)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/8417/repos/workspace/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/smb/SMBConnection.py", line 267, in retrieveFile
    return self.retrieveFileFromOffset(service_name, path, file_obj, 0L, -1L, timeout)
  File "/Users/8417/repos/workspace/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/smb/SMBConnection.py", line 283, in retrieveFileFromOffset
    raise NotConnectedError('Not connected to server')
smb.base.NotConnectedError: Not connected to server
```

Also tried:

```
>>> conn = SMBConnection('user', 'password', 'test_v1','v1/abc', use_ntlm_v2 = True)
>>> conn.retrieveFile('share', 'd2/check.csv', fp)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/8417/repos/workspace/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/smb/SMBConnection.py", line 267, in retrieveFile
    return self.retrieveFileFromOffset(service_name, path, file_obj, 0L, -1L, timeout)
  File "/Users/8417/repos/workspace/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/smb/SMBConnection.py", line 283, in retrieveFileFromOffset
    raise NotConnectedError('Not connected to server')
smb.base.NotConnectedError: Not connected to server
```

Comment: Can't you just mount the 'smb://location' as a local folder on your mac machine and use `shutil.copy2()` to copy the files?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian How can I mount it locally? If i do so, will it be in sync?

Comment: google: mount smb share mac

Answer (score 0):

The [SMBConnection constructor](https://pythonhosted.org/pysmb/api/smb_SMBConnection.html#smb.SMBConnection.SMBConnection.__init__) doesn't establish the connection, you need to call the [connect](https://pythonhosted.org/pysmb/api/smb_SMBConnection.html#smb.SMBConnection.SMBConnection.connect) method before retrieving the file.

Comment: I do not have the ip, just the name 'v1'

Comment: You need it to use pysmb. If your hostname is v1 you can probably find the IP with `ping v1`.